# Dynamic WebServiceCallout call results in "Variable does not exist: WebServiceCallout "

Tags: apex, webservices, callout

I want to encapsulate a `WebServiceCallout.invoke` to reuse it in various cases, so I've build the following static method

```
public static Object callSOAP(Object stub, Object request_x, Map<String, Object> response_map_x, Object response_x, String endpoint_x, String soapAction, String reqNameSpace, String reqName, String resNameSpace, String resName, String resType) {

    response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);

    WebServiceCallout.invoke(
        stub,
        request_x,
        response_map_x,
        new String[]{
            endpoint_x,
            soapAction,
            reqNameSpace,
            reqName,
            resNameSpace,
            resName,
            resType
        }
    );

    response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');

    return response_x;
}
```

However when I try to save this I get the following error:

```
Variable does not exist: WebServiceCallout
```

Like if some parameter is not valid and the system's class is not being recognised. According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_WebServiceCallout.htm) the parameters type are correct so no idea why this is failing or is there something I'm missing?.

Comment: Why got through the trouble when sf has already provided you the framework:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_webservicemock.htm. Or is this not for a test class ?

Comment: @Eric not for a test class, like a said for reuse purposes

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work when stub and request_x object have specific type.
Define StubBaseObject and RequestBaseObject:

```
public abstract class StubBaseObject{}
public abstract class RequestBaseObject{}

public static Map<String, Object> callSOAP(StubBaseObject stub, RequestBaseObject request_x, Map<String, Object> response_map_x, String endpoint_x, String soapAction, String reqNameSpace, String reqName, String resNameSpace, String resName, String resType) {
    WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            stub,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[]{
                    endpoint_x,
                    soapAction,
                    reqNameSpace,
                    reqName,
                    resNameSpace,
                    resName,
                    resType
            }
    );

    return response_map_x;
}
```

In Class that use callSOAP method you must extend specific stub class with StubBaseObject and specific request class with RequestBaseObject.

Comment: I like this approach. Do you have a full example of this?